# how to create a record inheriting the attributes of another record without explicitly rewriting them in C#

Tags: c#, record

Is it possible to factor the record parameters, to make the code easier to modify?

for exemple if I have :

```
public record A(int Param1, int Param2, int Param3, int Something);
public record B(int Param1, int Param2, int Param3, string OtherThing);
public record C(int Param1, int Param2, int Param3);
```

I want something like :

```
public record Base(int Param1, int Param2, int Param3);
public record A(int Something) : Base;
public record B(string OtherThing) : Base;
public record C() : Base;
```

So if someday I want to modify `Param1`, I can do it only once instead of doing it in 3 records.

Comment: You need to explain more what you're trying to accomplish. There's maybe inheritance, constructors, singleton pattern -- all different things that may or may not help to varying degrees.

Comment: @BurnsBA I want the same behavior of inheritance, but without explicitly writting all attributes. The idea is I have multiple records having sames attributes, so I want to create a generic record that store this generics attributes, and my specifics records can have them (like inheritage).

Answer (score 2):

The type signature of a record is the constructor definition of the type. As long as you want your constructor to have *all* the "attributes" as you call them, you need to type them all in.

What this means:

```
public record Specific1(int Attr3) : Global;
```

This won't compile because there is no constructor in `Global` with no parameters. Contrast this with the following instead:

```
public record Specific1(int Attr3) : Global(0, 0);
```

Which does compile, though might not do what you want. Again, the parameters you write in your record declaration are the parameters present in your constructor.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your awnser, indeed it's not what I'm looking for. I have just edited my question, maybe it is more clear and understandable ?

Comment: I understood what you want, I'm just trying to explain to you why it's impossible: "The type signature of a record is the constructor definition of the type".

Comment: Some alternatives are classes without constructors and `required` properties (C# 11), or source generators to write the constructors for you based on the fields provided.